# Improving someone's edit

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

If I select to "Improve" someone's proposed edit for just a minor issue like capitalizing a word or putting in punctuation they missed, does that take potential reputation from them?

As Knights who say Ni mentioned, that box is pretty small. I have a feeling I would have missed it entirely. Plus it's automatically checked. Can we make this bigger or more noticeable and perhaps explain to 2K rep newcomers what it's there for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an inappropriately small check box above to `Save edits`, which says `Suggested edit was helpful`. This is what it looks like:

[image]

If you check this, then they gain the +2 for submitting a helpful edit. If you don't check this, then they lose the +2. This also counts  as an acceptance or rejection - if you say it's helpful, Community will accept. Otherwise, Community will reject.

This is an example improvement:

[image]

And another:

[image]

There is a solid justification for this: Suggested edits may not necessarily be complete, but they may still be helpful. If an edit calls to your attention that a post is bad, but does not correct everything, it's typically still helpful. If fits any of the reject reasons, then reject it, but improve and reject if it needs improvement.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't selected to "Improve" anyone's edits yet because I didn't want to screw them over out of deserved rep.

Comment: @ChristopherW Understandably. Just make sure you reject when it should be rejected, and you'll be alright!

Comment: You say inappropriately small. Can I add in this question for it's size to be made bigger?

Comment: @ChristopherW Feel free. I suggest not changing the focus of the question too dramatically, but it's a valid point which you are free to note.

Comment: I would say that if you need to "improve" the edit @ChristopherW, chances are they don't deserve any rep... for instance if there's still spelling errors there's little excuse as they're all nicely underlined in red.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards, I think that's a bit extreme. Perhaps they just didn't spot it. Obviously extreme changes shouldn't be necessary for a "good/helpful" edit, but at least people are making an effort. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: It might be extreme in certain cases @ChristopherW, use your own personal judgement of course, but how else are people to learn? For instance [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2092007) I'd have edited and not marked as helpful; the first line is completely pointless, there's an error in the title and it's missing the generic tag, it only has a version specific one.

Comment: I guess it will take a few more reviews to get used to these new shoes @benisuǝqbackwards.

Comment: Or you can choose to completely ignore me @ChristopherW; there's no compulsion to agree with anything I've written :-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards, 1, we have to stop commenting back and forth to each other. Your name is quite difficult to respond to. 2, I'm not above taking your suggestions. You've obviously done your homework on the way Stack Overflow runs and I hope I can be there one day too.